# Text to the right of a \section{title} in LaTeX (the normal case is, text comes below)

Tags: latex

I use LaTeX, but I only consider myself an average user. I have a special need. If I have a `\section{Something}` and I would like `{ something else }` on the **same vertical line** as the section. But aligned right. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to do this once... don't. Find some other way to present that single bit of information. `\hfil[l][l]` will *work*, but it can play havoc with the Table of Contents if you're not careful, and in general you just shouldn't go there.

If you want to add a little bit of extra information to *every* section title, or even most of them, you're going to have to hack the sectioning commands. You'll probably end up declaring some kind of `\customsection[Optional ToC text]{Section title}{Extra information you want on the right side}` command. If you can, use [the `titlesec` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/); it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about `\hfil` and `\hfilll`. When are they used?

Comment: Usually, when you're making quick and dirty hacks :) They're part of the original TeX and are described in detail in Knuth's TeXBook, but all three are basically the same. The more `l`s the command has, the more powerful it is: two `\hfil` on a line will expand to the same size (useful for centering), but throw in one `\hfill` and it will overpower the `\hfil`s and dominate all the space itself. `\hfilll` is the nuclear bomb of TeX glue commands, and will crush everything in its path... use *it* with caution.

Comment: It seems SuperUser botched the formatting on that comment... I'm pretty sure I got it correct, and there's just a bug in the SU code. I'll see if it gets fixed soon, and if not file a bug report on MSO....

Comment: I guess my question is, what's the point of overpowering the other things like `\hfil` if they'll completely disappear? You could just not include them.

Comment: If you're writing in pure TeX and you control everything, there's *not* much point to them. If you're doing complicated stuff with both standard and custom macros, you'll learn to love them.

Comment: Thank you!

By the way! I've been thinking about buying Knuth's TeXBook. I'd like to dwelve deeper into the world of TeX and LaTeX, but when it comes to something like this issue, I'm a quite lost. At the moment I'm mostly using what's available in the The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e. Do you think Knuth's book is the book I should buy?

Comment: Honestly, it's not that useful unless you're going to be writing a lot of plain TeX macros. LaTeX is rather different, and the TeXBook was written before LaTeX even existed. The LaTeX Companion second edition has been *far* more useful to me; the TeXBook is more an occasional reference than anything else. You can probably just grab it from a library should you need it.

Answer (score 3):

Aha, I found something that may be useful! The [`titlesec` package](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=titlesec) has a bunch of customizations for titles, including section titles.

Here is a [PDF of examples](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/archive/titlesecex.pdf) which contains something like this, #8.

Comment: Yes it looks really useful and I didn't know about it! :-) For my simple needs this time I'll go with the \hfill solution (I'm just writing a resume), but I'm sure it will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use \hfill .

```
\section{Something \hfill something else}
```

Note, that answer your requirement for appearance, I'm not too sure whether you only want "Something" considered as part of the title, because the above solution consider "Something something else" as the title.

Comment: I was going to post that, but I figured the idea was *not* to have it be part of the title. Plus, that would probably break the table of contents and other things.

Comment: You can still define another text to appear in the table of contents, though. Dunno about how hyperref treats this. But that thing breaks pretty easily on nearly everything that is unusual, so I don't expect much anymore.

Comment: Thank you! I went with the \hfill solution. I won't be using a TOC in this document (my resume), if I need to I'll probably use the titlesec package. I'm choosing the other answer as my accepted one, as both posts where posted 11 hours ago and the other one is a bit more detailed and has one more vote. It's at times like this I would like the option to pick two accepted answers. Thank you! (And of course I up-vote)